# querying values from the table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to get values from table the problem I am facing is that regardless of what the input is it gives me the result of both rows. I want to match the input ID with the ID in the table. This is the code I am trying to use[Image of the table is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqGhO.jpg) the file name is linked with the javascript file where I have a click function and this javascript(global.js) file is linked with another file having text box.
My main file code is below

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>products</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            Item: 
            <input type="text" required id="item">
            <input type="submit" id="item-submit" value="Grab"> 
            <div id="item-data"></div>

            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script> 
            <script src="js/global.js"></script> 

    </body>
</html>
```

global.js file code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#item-submit').click(function(){     

        var item = $('input#item').val();    
        if ($.trim(item) != ''){             
            $.post('ajax/name.php',{item:name}, function(data){ 
                $('div#item-data').text(data);  

            });

        }

    })
});
```

name.php file code is below

```
 require '../db/connect.php';

    $sql = "SELECT BarcodeID, shirts, price FROM clothes WHERE BarcodeID = ($_POST['name']) ";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo " " . $row["BarcodeID"]. " shirt color:  " . $row["shirts"]. " price: " . $row["price"];
        }
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: You may want to re-format your question by approving the edit made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $id=$_POST['item']; // your post variable
    $sql = "SELECT BarcodeID, shirts, price FROM clothes WHERE BarcodeID=".$id;

     $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo " " . $row["BarcodeID"]. " shirt color:  " . $row["shirts"]. " price: " . $row["price"];
        }
}
else
{
echo "No results found";
}
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: These are the errors I got. Line 40 is          $id=$_POST['name'];
and line 43 is  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\ajax\name.php on line <i>40</i></th>
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\ajax\name.php on line <i>43</i></th>

Comment: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\ajax\name.php on line <i>44</i>

Line 44 is     if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)

Comment: Test the query by giving direct value 1 as $id. Then  Note the result. ie   $sql = "SELECT BarcodeID, shirts, price FROM clothes WHERE BarcodeID=1";

Comment: Yes this is working correctly. This means my name.php file is not getting the input. So the issue can be in my global.js file.

Comment: ok. you can check the POST is working or not  by using echo $_POST['item']; exit();

Comment: Basically I should change my this line echo " " . $row["BarcodeID"]. " shirt color:  " . $row["shirts"]. " price: " . $row["price"]; to echo $_POST['item']; exit();

It gives me the same error  Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\ajax\name.php on line <i>44

Comment: echo $_POST['item']; exit(); give this top of the page and check.

Comment: ie nothing POST receives . error in global.js  in  {item:name}  put {id:item} and use  
echo $_POST['id']; exit();

Comment: It worked. Tried in the full code. Now I am getting the proper result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query :

```
"SELECT BarcodeID, shirts, price FROM clothes WHERE BarcodeID = '{$_POST['name']}'"
```

And why are you comparing `BarcodeID` with name?

> Side note : Your query is unsafe. Read this
>   [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Below is the javascript file this global.js file is linked with my main file with following code for text box and submit button 
<input type="text" required id="item"> <!--text box -->
<input type="submit" id="item-submit" value="Grab"> <!--button -->

.js file ->
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('input#item-submit').click(function(){  
  
  var item = $('input#item').val();  
  if ($.trim(item) != ''){    
   $.post('ajax/name.php',{item:name}, function(data){ 
    $('div#item-data').text(data); 
    
   });
  
  }
  
 })
});

Comment: Please don't do like this. Don't dump your code here. Please edit your question.

Comment: Just one thing. If you are using like this : `{item:name}` then you need to use `$_POST['item']` not `$_POST['name']`.

Comment: ohh, Is rest of the code fine ?. Item is the variable carrying the data name right?

Comment: Yes right.Please accept my answer if it's helpful to you.

Comment: Its still giving me error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\ajax\name.php on line <i>41</i></th></tr> </table></font>

Line 41 is this $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

Comment: I think you are missing semicolon (`;`) on that line.

Comment: I do have a semicolon.